# FE1.1s USB Hub and GL827L SD Card Reader

Tags: pcb, schematics, sd, usb-hub

I'm trying to make a 4-port USB hub using the FE1.1s IC, one of the outputs of which is the GL827L IC as an SD card reader. when i connect my usb hub to computer, my usb hub is detected but sd card reader is not detected.

When i tried removing the usb hub and leaving the sd card reader, it worked fine, however when i reconnected it, it was not detected anymore.

Please tell me, what's wrong from my following circuit schematic. I would really appreciate your feedback.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgVSEU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My initial thought is that the schematic looks to be lacking some decoupling capacitors close to FE1.1s and GL827L VDD pins. Could be worth adding some.

Comment: well, i will try to add some decoupling capacitors. thanks for your feedback @Klas-Kenny !

Comment: i've tried to add some decoupling capacitors, but it still doesn't work! are there any other suggestions?